# Seam: Reset form validation after modalpanel closes

Tags: validation, richfaces, seam, reset

Im struggling with the following problem:

- I have a modalPanel for adding a new person on my Richfaces view
- I have two buttons "Save" and "Cancel"
- Some input fields are required with required="true" attribute on h:inputText component
- when I leave one or more required fields empty and cancel the form/modalpanel, the modalpanel closes
- When I now want to add a new person, I instantiate a new Person object on my backing bean, reRender the elements in the modalPanel.
- ModalPanel opens up again
- Sometime it happens, that the failed validation on my first attempt to create a new person impeded the reRendering of the validation of my modalPanel input fields
- I see the new empty fields from my new person object, but the view has the validation error messages from the last attempt?

So, how can I make sure to reset all backend logic, form and buttons by clicking the "Add Person" button?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a new conversation when you add new person. Mark the method with `@Begin`. This way it will disregard everything that happened in the previous conversation.

Then when you push the save button, you can mark that action with `@End`

The cancel button can and should be marked with `@End(beforeRedirect=true)` (beforeRedirect=true) is optional, but can be helpful

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. Im in a long-conversation... so I can not create a new one...

Comment: Of course you can. It just depends what you want to do with the old one. If it is essential you keep the information, then I can see your point. So I am guessing then you cannot totally end the conversation. However what you can do is use a nested conversation. So you nest a conversation when adding person, and then merge it once you save